# How to show image and text at same cell in QTableWidget in PyQt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I want to have a table with 2 or 3 columns with rows that shows image and text alongside each other in PyQt (I am using python3.5 and PyQt 5). First I chose QListWidget but it was limited to only one column. I figured out that QTableWidget is the best way for doing this. But when I put an image for a cell in the table the text of that cell is not being shown at bottom of it. How can I make the cell show text and image in proper place?
This my code:

```
self.main_table = QTableWidget(self)
self.main_table.setGeometry(QRect(20, 140, 600, 330))
sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.main_table.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
self.main_table.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
self.main_table.setLayoutDirection(Qt.LeftToRight)
self.main_table.setLocale(QLocale(QLocale.Persian, QLocale.Iran))
self.main_table.setInputMethodHints(Qt.ImhNone)
self.main_table.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
self.main_table.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
self.main_table.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
self.main_table.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
self.main_table.setTabKeyNavigation(False)
self.main_table.setShowGrid(False)
self.main_table.setCornerButtonEnabled(False)
self.main_table.setIconSize(QSize(210,150))

self.main_table.setRowCount(2)
self.main_table.setColumnCount(2)


self.main_table.setObjectName("main_table")
self.main_table.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
self.main_table.horizontalHeader().setHighlightSections(False)
self.main_table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
self.main_table.verticalHeader().setHighlightSections(False)
self.main_table.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(250)
self.main_table.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(250)

self.item = QTableWidgetItem(QIcon('content/img/food.png'),'Food')
self.main_table.setItem(0 , 0, self.item)
```

Comment: You could indicate how you want the image and text to be displayed in a cell

Comment: @eyllanesc how to do that?

Comment: For example the size of the image with respect to the cell and with respect to the text, its position, you want it to be an icon, or that occupy the whole cell, the text is centered or aligned to the left. There are many variants

Comment: @eyllanesc any size that choose for QIcon the text is in the right side and it's position doesn't change.

Comment: Is that what you want?

Comment: @eyllanesc I want to have the text on the bottom of image in each cell.

Comment: That's why I ask you to put an image showing what you want. Have you worked with QTableView?

Comment: @eyllanesc no. would that widget have all tablewidget features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest is to use a create a custom widget where we locate the elements as we want, the following code implements the icon appears at the top and the text below it.

```
class CustomWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text, img, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self._text = text
        self._img = img

        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.lbPixmap = QLabel(self)
        self.lbText = QLabel(self)
        self.lbText.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.layout().addWidget(self.lbPixmap)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.lbText)

        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.lbPixmap.setPixmap(QPixmap(self._img).scaled(self.lbPixmap.size(),Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        self.lbText.setText(self._text)


    @pyqtProperty(str)
    def img(self):
        return self._img

    @img.setter
    def total(self, value):
        if self._img == value:
            return
        self._img = value
        self.initUi()

    @pyqtProperty(str)
    def text(self):
        return self._text

    @text.setter
    def text(self, value):
        if self._text == value:
            return
        self._text = value
        self.initUi()
```

Then add the widget through the `setCellWidget()` function to add them and scale the space of each cell with `resizeColumnsToContents()` and `resizeRowsToContents()` as I show below:

```
class TableWidget(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QTableWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setColumnCount(5)
        self.setRowCount(5)
        for i in range(self.columnCount()):
            for j in range(self.rowCount()):
                lb = CustomWidget(str(i)+str(j), "/path/of/image")
                self.setCellWidget(i, j, lb)

        self.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.resizeRowsToContents()
        self.cellClicked.connect(self.onCellClicked)

    @pyqtSlot(int, int)
    def onCellClicked(self, row, column):
        w = self.cellWidget(row, column)
        print(w.text, w.img)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    tw = TableWidget()

    tw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: yes. This is exactly what i want by shape. But I need every cell's info like text and name, ... . This widget cant' give me this Things.

Comment: @Nimda Explain better, I do not understand what you mean by text and name

Comment: I have a function with this code:    `def populatescnte(self,item):
        itemnum = self.scentence_listw.count()
        exec("item{} = QListWidgetItem(QIcon('{}'),'{}')".format(itemnum+1,url,item.text()))
        exec("self.scentence_listw.addItem(item{})".format(itemnum+1))`                it runs when the user clicks on any items of that QTableWidget and adds an item to a QListWidget. I need the info that comes with the item when clicking event occur. But the custom widget doesn't give me this info.

Comment: That's easy, I update my answer and let you know. :P